# Is it possible to fix stuck LCD pixels using flashing colours?

Tags: electronics

The LCD of my $700 smartphone has a stuck subpixel (blue, almost invisible due to the high screen resolution).

There are literally dozens of apps that claim to fix stuck pixels.

For example: Here's a [video that apparently fixes them](http://ismashphone.com/2010/05/iphone-stuck-pixel-fixer.html) by flashing multiple colours rapidly.

Is it really possible to fix stuck pixels in this way?

Comment: Can you post a reference to an app that claims that?

Comment: Here's one: http://ismashphone.com/2010/05/iphone-stuck-pixel-fixer.html

Comment: The great thing about Jamie's link (which I edited into the question) is that it is free and fast. I expect a comment (NOT an anecdotal answer!) from the OP telling us whether it worked for them.

Comment: I get the feeling kinda what the OP was after was not a skeptical answer, but more a technical answer on how to fix one of his electronic devices. I didn't find a more fitting SE for the question though. Skeptics kinda is "oh it didn't fit anywhere else, just formulate it the right way, and you can post it here!".

Comment: Commercial claims are on-topic here.

Comment: No no, I am curious to know if it's can really fix it, or it's just placebo effect like those "signal booster" stickers

Comment: The fact that you have to press on the screen while using it makes me wonder whether it is the pressure rather than the app that makes it work (for some people...)

Comment: Are you sure your phone has an LCD screen? Many new phones are using AMOLED screens, so a fix that works with LCD may not work with AMOLED.

Comment: Ah, the flashing video didn't work. I did not press the area though, because if I tapped, the animation would stop. I don't know if I have LCD or amoled, i think LCD